# Remove Appended Element on Second Click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When you click the gray heart, the `div` gets appended to a container on the right side.  I want it to remove the appended element when you click the pink heart.  It just keeps appending the content...

```
$('.icon-heart').click(function(){
    var $newEl = $(this).closest('.color-container').html();

        if( $(this).css('color') === 'rgb(204, 204, 204)' ) { // if gray
            $(this).css('color', 'rgb(234, 76, 136)'); // turn to pink

            $('.b').append($newEl); // append new element


        } else if( $(this).css('color') === 'rgb(234, 76, 136)' ) { // if pink
            $(this).css('color', 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'); // turn to gray
            $newEl.remove(); // remove appended element
        }

});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDk6s/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there should be easier ways to do that, checking a returned color from the browser is never a very good idea, as it's not very consistent.

Instead, add a class

```
.pink {
    color: #EA4C88;
}
```

Then do

```
$('.icon-heart').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is('.pink')) {
        if ($(this).data('el')) $(this).data('el').remove();
    }else{
        var clone = $(this).closest('.color-container').clone();
        $('.b').append(clone);
        $(this).data('el', clone);
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('pink');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDk6s/5/)

Comment: Very nice.  I'll make sure to use .addClass/.removeClass/.toggleClass more often.  What does `.data('el')` do?  I don't know what `el` means.

Comment: It just stores arbitrary data, `el` is just a key I picked, short for "element", as it stores the element to be removed on the next click.

Comment: Clever - this is a cleaner solution than mine... although I was merely fixing what was wrong for him, I wasn't improving anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
else if ($(this).css('color') === 'rgb(234, 76, 136)') { // if pink
    $(this).css('color', 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'); // turn to gray
    $('.b div').last().remove(); // remove appended element
}
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/XDk6s/3/

Comment: This doesn't remove the correct entry.  Click on Blue, then Pink, then Blue again.  The Pink gets removed instead of the blue one.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually grabbing the element you need to remove - you're trying to remove a second copy of the element that hasn't been attached anywhere.  To remove the element, you want to find it in your second list, then remove it.  So the second part of your if statement becomes this:

```js
else if ($(this).css('color') === 'rgb(234, 76, 136)') { // if pink
    $(this).css('color', 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'); // turn to gray
    $('.b').find(".color-block[data-color='" + $(this).closest(".color-block").data("color") + "']").remove();
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XDk6s/7/

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!  Never though of using the `color-data` approach.